# Relation between erfc and the BER

Tags: modulation

Antipodal Signalling has a bit error probability of $P_b = \frac{1}{2} \mathrm{erfc}\big(\sqrt{\frac{E_s}{N_0}}\big)$ and on-off-signalling has a bit error probability of $\frac{1}{2} \mathrm{erfc}\big(\sqrt{\frac{E_s}{2 N_0}}\big)$. Why does this correspond to a higher SNR of 3 dB which we need for on-off-signalling to achieve the same bit error probability as with antipodal signalling?

I know that the factor 2 corresponds to 3 dB. But the complementary error function does not decrease by a factor of 2 but by a factor of $\sqrt{2}$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming your bit error probability formulas are correct, for antipodal signalling

$$P_{b, aS} = \frac{1}{2} \mathrm{erfc}\left(\sqrt{\frac{E_{s,aS}}{N_0}}\right)$$

and for on-off signalling

$$P_{b, oS} = \frac{1}{2} \mathrm{erfc}\left(\sqrt{\frac{E_{s,oS}}{2N_0}}\right)$$

If these two error probability are identical, i.e. $P_{b, aS} = P_{b, oS}$,

$$\frac{1}{2} \mathrm{erfc}\left(\sqrt{\frac{E_{s,aS}}{N_0}}\right) = \frac{1}{2} \mathrm{erfc}\left(\sqrt{\frac{E_{s,oS}}{2N_0}}\right) \tag{1}$$

Because both $\mathrm{erfc(.)}$ and $\sqrt{.}$ are [bijective](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bijection) functions, $(1)$ implies $\frac{E_{s,oS}}{N_0} = 2\frac{E_{s,aS}}{N_0}$ in linear scale and 3dB difference in log scale.

Comment: great, thx very much!

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the error probability formula in terms of the average energy only makes one miss important aspects of the comparison. In antipodal signaling, the *signal* output (at the sampling time) of the matched filter is $\pm A$ and is achieved by transmitting energy $E_b$ during *each* signaling interval. The (noisy) matched filter output is compared to a threshold of $0$ to decide whether the noise-free output was supposed to be $+A$ or $-A$. If the (zero-mean Gaussian) noise has standard deviation $\sigma$, the error probability is $Q\left(\frac{A}{\sigma}\right)$ where $Q(\cdot)$ is the complementary standard Gaussian cumulative distribution function.

In *on-off* signaling, the signal outputs are $2A$ and $0$ and are compared to a threshold of $A$ to determine if the noise-free output should have been $2A$ or $0$. This gives the *same* error probability as antipodal signaling.
**But,** it is necessary to transmit *four times* as much energy ($4E_b$) in the ON state to get the signal output level to be *double* that of the level with antipodal signaling.  Assuming ZEROes and ONEs to be equally likely to be transmitted, the *average* energy transmitted per bit in on-off signaling *is* $2E_b$ as compared to $E_b$ in antipodal signaling, which is the doubling referred to in your question. But the *peak* energy is four times as large which means that more powerful (and thus, more likely, *larger*) transmitters are needed; something to keep in mind in applications where power consumption and weight of the transmitter electronics is an issue.